# why does sasuke have sharingan in both eyes but kakashi only has it in one?

Tags: naruto

I always wondered why Sasuke has it both eyes, and Kakashi only has it in one, because they both have the same thing, right, so yeah

Comment: If you're new to the series, this is explained later on

Comment: Continue watching/reading it.

Comment: I noticed that your questions seem to be because you did not finish watching/reading these shows/manga. I suggest you finish them first and try to see if you still have questions that you think are still unanswered.

Comment: Welcome to Anime SE :-) Buddy please please please don't search for your question into Google until you finish the series. Naruto series is full of secrets but they will be answer surely so please don't search on internet because internet is full of spoil. Just finish it and if you had any unanswered question then ask here. we are here always . so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Sasuke is an Uchiha. He was born with both Sharingan eyes.

Kakashi is not an Uchiha, he was not born with any Sharingans. During a mission in his youth, one of his eyes was injured and he was gifted a Sharingan eye by an Uchiha teammate who was fatally injured (or so everyone thought - that became an important piece of a later story arc).

Comment: Thank you so much dear friend. You answered without any spoil. You did great. I did up vote your answer